# C++ slow in sorting using lambda

Tags: c++, performance, sorting, lambda

I am trying to solve the Google Hash Challenge 2020 problem. In this problem, you have some libraries and for each library, you have a list of books. Each book has a global score (defined as an integer).
Now, I wanted to sort the books on each library by decreasing score and I wrote this

```
for (auto it = inst.libraries.begin(); it != inst.libraries.end(); ++it)
{
    std::sort((*it).books.begin(), (*it).books.end(), [inst](long const &b1, long const &b2) -> bool { return inst.scores[b1] > inst.scores[b2]; });
}
```

`inst` is where I keep my data. The previous code (with O2 option) runs in about 8 minutes for an instance with 1000 libraries and less than 1000 books on each library.

Are there some errors in my c++ code? What should I do to to get better performances?

Comment: Regarding the other post: please read the comments there to understand why it got downvoted. Also, it has nothing to do with your question.

Comment: What's the type of `books`?

Comment: @MrBeanBremen Yes, now I see. I am sorry. Thank you for your explanation,

Comment: @HeapOverflow books is a `std::vector`.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen OMG the comments under that old answer are infuriating. People thinking that an already reverse sorted list is a worst case... sigh...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your lambda is taking a copy of `inst` for every invocation to `sort`. Change it to `[&inst]` instead.